# After logged in from a Api i got a response of json. Now need to show the arrays length as count for my notification icon . How to do it?

Tags: json, api, flutter, authentication, dart

Here is my all operational code which i am trying to fetching this json data in my App.
here is the json which i am getting as response

```
{
"user_id": 1,
"user_name": "Mr Admin",
"api_token": "6S3gRnPy55JKWyiOF7SwtYO12waZ8ozSyIHUNs2XSEcMh0DfTbpP5k51y2mL",
"notifications": [
    {
        "id": "d54ee0cc-054a-4d51-a53b-5f6f658841ae",
        "type": "App\\Notifications\\HandSlipStatusNotification",
        "notifiable_id": 1,
        "notifiable_type": "App\\User",
        "data": {
            "payment_id": 471,
            "generate_payment_id": "10200471",
            "message": "Hand Slip Settled.",
            "amount": 850
        },
        "read_at": null,
        "created_at": "2020-10-12 15:50:38",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-12 15:50:38"
    },
    {
        "id": "aedb7880-4201-4805-b017-62242dfed741",
        "type": "App\\Notifications\\HandSlipStatusNotification",
        "notifiable_id": 1,
        "notifiable_type": "App\\User",
        "data": {
            "payment_id": 471,
            "generate_payment_id": "10200471",
            "message": "Hand Slip Disbursed.",
            "amount": 850
        },
        "read_at": null,
        "created_at": "2020-10-12 15:50:25",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-12 15:50:25"
    },
    {
        "id": "99b433b1-9432-44ae-a57f-fcb4ff92872f",
        "type": "App\\Notifications\\HandSlipStatusNotification",
        "notifiable_id": 1,
        "notifiable_type": "App\\User",
        "data": {
            "payment_id": 471,
            "generate_payment_id": "10200471",
            "message": "Hand Slip Approved.",
            "amount": 850
        },
        "read_at": null,
        "created_at": "2020-10-12 15:50:08",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-12 15:50:08"
    },
```

login.dart

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

    import '../sharePreference.dart';
    import 'homepage.dart';
    
    
    class Login extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _LoginState createState() => _LoginState();
    }
    
    class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
    
    var notification ;
      bool isprocesscomplete = false;
      TextEditingController _userController = TextEditingController();
      TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
      final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
      String BaseUrl = "my url";
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 100, 20, 20),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Login",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 30,
                    ),
                    Card(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 220,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: _userController,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Username"),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                              child: TextField(
                                controller: _passwordController,
                                obscureText: true,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 60,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      child: RaisedButton(
                        color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (_userController.text == "" ||
                              _passwordController.text == "") {
                            final snackBar = SnackBar(
                                content: Text("Enter Username and Password"));
                            _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
                          } else {
                            signIn(_userController.text, _passwordController.text);
                          }
                        },
                        child: ProgressButton(),
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(16),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    FlatButton(
                      child: Text("Forgot password"),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget ProgressButton() {
        if (isprocesscomplete != false) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.white));
        } else {
          return new Text(
            "Sign In",
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 15.0,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    
      void signIn(String username, String password) async {
        setState(() {
          isprocesscomplete = true;
        });
        var response = await http.post(BaseUrl,
            headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
            body: json.encode({
              "username": username,
              "password": password,
            }));
    
        Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
        notification = value["notifications"];
        // print('Response ${response.body}');
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          try {
            ///You don't need it but it will be cool for show progress dialgo for 4 second then redirect even if we get reslut
            Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
              // 5s over make it false
              setState(() {
                isprocesscomplete = false;
              });
            });
    
            Map<String, dynamic> value = json.decode(response.body);
    
    
            print('Response ${response.body}');
            SharedPrefrence().setToken(value['api_token'].toString());
            SharedPrefrence().setName(value['user_name']);
            SharedPrefrence().setUserId(value['user_id'].toString());
    
            ///This is used when user loged in you can set this true,
            ///next time you open you need to check loginc in main.dart or splashscreen if this is true if it is true then
            ///redirect to home page it is false then redirect to Login page
            ///When you logout the app make sure you set this as false like "SharedPrefrence().setLoggedIn(false);"
            SharedPrefrence().setLoggedIn(true);
    
            ///Redirect to Home page
            Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => HomePage(
                                          user_name: value['user_name'],
                                          api_token: value['api_token'],
                                            id : value['user_id'],
                                          notification: notification,
    
                                        )),
                                    ModalRoute.withName("/login"));
    
          } catch (e) {
            e.toString();
            final snackBar =
            SnackBar(content: Text("something wrong,Try again "));
            _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
          }
        } else {
          var message = value['error'];
          final snackBar = SnackBar( backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent[700],
              content: Text(message.toString()));
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
        }
      }
    }
```

in my homepage.dart page i am trying to show the count of arrays which i am getting from that json to my notification widget. The notification should show the length of arrays as count. here is my homepage code.

```
 import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../sharePreference.dart';
import 'login.dart';
import 'login.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

  String user_name;
  final api_token;
  final id ;
 final  List<dynamic> notification ;
  // List data ;
  HomePage({ this.user_name, this.api_token , this.id, this.notification });


  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}



class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


  String nametoprint;
  String tokentoprint;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future name = SharedPrefrence().getName();
    name.then((data) async {
      nametoprint = data;
      print(nametoprint);
    });

    Future token= SharedPrefrence().getToken();
    token.then((data) async {
      tokentoprint= data;
      print(tokentoprint);
    });
  }



  int counter = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Cash-Management"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          actions: [

            new Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications), onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    counter = 0;
                  });
                }),
                counter != 0 ? new Positioned(
                  right: 11,
                  top: 11,
                  child: new Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    ),
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minWidth: 14,
                      minHeight: 14,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      '$counter',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 8,
                      ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ) : new Container()
              ],
            ),
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()),
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "${widget.user_name}",
                    // "  ${widget.username} ",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "${widget.api_token}",
                    // "  ${widget.username} ",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "${widget.id}",
                    // "  ${widget.username} ",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  Text(" ${nametoprint} "),
                  Text("$nametoprint"),
                  Text("$tokentoprint"),
                ],
              ),
            ),

Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  height: 300,
  child:   ListView.builder(
      itemCount: widget.notification == null ?  0 : widget.notification.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(widget.notification[index] ["id"]),
          subtitle: Text(widget.notification[index]["type"]),

        );
      }),
),



          ],
        ),

        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
          print("Increment Counter");
          setState(() {
            counter++;
          });
        }, child: Icon(Icons.add),),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have added the response model for that json.
responsemodel.dart

```
  class UserDetails {
  int userId;
  String userName;
  String apiToken;
  List<Notifications> notifications;

  UserDetails({this.userId, this.userName, this.apiToken, this.notifications});

  UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userId = json['user_id'];
    userName = json['user_name'];
    apiToken = json['api_token'];
    if (json['notifications'] != null) {
      notifications = new List<Notifications>();
      json['notifications'].forEach((v) {
        notifications.add(new Notifications.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['user_id'] = this.userId;
    data['user_name'] = this.userName;
    data['api_token'] = this.apiToken;
    if (this.notifications != null) {
      data['notifications'] =
          this.notifications.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Notifications {
  String id;
  String type;
  int notifiableId;
  String notifiableType;
  Data data;
  Null readAt;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  Notifications(
      {this.id,
        this.type,
        this.notifiableId,
        this.notifiableType,
        this.data,
        this.readAt,
        this.createdAt,
        this.updatedAt});

  Notifications.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    type = json['type'];
    notifiableId = json['notifiable_id'];
    notifiableType = json['notifiable_type'];
    data = json['data'] != null ? new Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
    readAt = json['read_at'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['notifiable_id'] = this.notifiableId;
    data['notifiable_type'] = this.notifiableType;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.toJson();
    }
    data['read_at'] = this.readAt;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int paymentId;
  String generatePaymentId;
  String message;
  int amount;

  Data({this.paymentId, this.generatePaymentId, this.message, this.amount});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    paymentId = json['payment_id'];
    generatePaymentId = json['generate_payment_id'];
    message = json['message'];
    amount = json['amount'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['payment_id'] = this.paymentId;
    data['generate_payment_id'] = this.generatePaymentId;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    data['amount'] = this.amount;
    return data;
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfTvq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to Map your existing json to a Model, something like this

```
class UserDetails {
  int userId;
  String userName;
  String apiToken;
  List<Notifications> notifications;

  UserDetails({this.userId, this.userName, this.apiToken, this.notifications});

  UserDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userId = json['user_id'];
    userName = json['user_name'];
    apiToken = json['api_token'];
    if (json['notifications'] != null) {
      notifications = new List<Notifications>();
      json['notifications'].forEach((v) {
        notifications.add(new Notifications.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['user_id'] = this.userId;
    data['user_name'] = this.userName;
    data['api_token'] = this.apiToken;
    if (this.notifications != null) {
      data['notifications'] =
          this.notifications.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Notifications {
  String id;
  String type;
  int notifiableId;
  String notifiableType;
  Data data;
  Null readAt;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;

  Notifications(
      {this.id,
      this.type,
      this.notifiableId,
      this.notifiableType,
      this.data,
      this.readAt,
      this.createdAt,
      this.updatedAt});

  Notifications.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    type = json['type'];
    notifiableId = json['notifiable_id'];
    notifiableType = json['notifiable_type'];
    data = json['data'] != null ? new Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
    readAt = json['read_at'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    data['notifiable_id'] = this.notifiableId;
    data['notifiable_type'] = this.notifiableType;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.toJson();
    }
    data['read_at'] = this.readAt;
    data['created_at'] = this.createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = this.updatedAt;
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  int paymentId;
  String generatePaymentId;
  String message;
  int amount;

  Data({this.paymentId, this.generatePaymentId, this.message, this.amount});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    paymentId = json['payment_id'];
    generatePaymentId = json['generate_payment_id'];
    message = json['message'];
    amount = json['amount'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['payment_id'] = this.paymentId;
    data['generate_payment_id'] = this.generatePaymentId;
    data['message'] = this.message;
    data['amount'] = this.amount;
    return data;
  }
}
```

After converting to Model, you should access this model, Like,

```
UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
```

and to access the details inside you should do something like this.

```
String name = userDetails.userName;
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your suggession brother. I have created the model class in responsemodel.dart page . But got confused how to show this notifications in my homepage in listview.builder or how to show a single data in a text field from the model. Can you edit my code for the solution. It will be very helpfull for me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share the wireframe or any reference UI, so that I can get an exact idea how you want the Textfield in ListView.

Comment: i have added a ss. under the question. I can fetch some data in my existing code. But now i want to fetch data as u suggested me to do . basically i want to know how to use model to show data in my homepage in text or in a listview.builder. It will be helpful if u help me with your knowledge.